# Easiest way to generate a report of the list of all repositories in a github org

Tags: github, github-api

I am not able to find any option in my GitHub enterprise UI to generate a report that lists all repositories in a given org. Is that possible through UI? If not what is the easiest way to generate that list using GitHub rest api? I guess the rest api will send a json response with a ton of information rather than providing a clean report only related to the names of the repositories.
Kindly provide any suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Using the Repositories API, shell, curl, and jq:

```
URL="https://api.github.com/orgs/myorgs/repos/per_page=100"
JSONDATA=$(curl -sL "$URL")
LENGTH=$(printf "%s" "$JSONDATA" | jq length)
for (( i=0; i < "$LENGTH"; i++ )); do
    REPONAME=$(printf "%s" "$JSONDATA" | jq -r '.['$i'] | .name')
    REPOLIST+=("$REPONAME")
done

REPOCOUNT=${#REPOLIST[@]}
for (( index=0; index < "$REPOCOUNT"; index++ )); do
    echo "$index: ${REPOLIST["$index"]}\n"
done
```

`jq` is used to parse the JSON response object.

Comment: Thanks mehtaarn. However, when i try the above exactly as you provided except for my URL then i get below error :-
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index object with number
jq: error (at <stdin>:3): Cannot index object with number

Comment: @Ashley Be sure to change the “myorg” in the URL string to a valid organization. If you run the code as is, you will get the error you described. If this doesn’t work, will you tell me what shell you are using?

Comment: Thanks mehtaarn000. Actually my api url is correct and is using the correct org. I am however executing  this on my windows machine using gitbash

Comment: Ah i guess i may have to provide user credentials as well correct. Can i simply use the below format for api call
URL="https://myusername:mypassword@github.****.com/api/v3/orgs/myorgname/repos"

Comment: You could definitely try it, but I can't guarantee the results. I'm using MacOS, and don't have a Windows machine readily available, so I apologize if I couldn't help you.

Comment: Actually, instead of using the URL you just commented,  maybe try to authenticate directly with `curl`. Try this: `curl -sLu "user:token" "$URL"`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227655/discussion-between-mehtaarn000-and-ashley).

Comment: Thanks! After adding that username:password i was able to fetch the results but the script only returns very few repos from the org though mine is admin creds that has overall permissions. also the repos are printed one after the other. is there a way to get list of all 1000 plus repos through some pagination or something and each in a new line?

Comment: My new answer should print number: reponame for each Repository.

Comment: Thanks it does but then they are not in new line and it only fetches 29 repos though there are 1000+

Comment: The max number of repositories you can get at one time using the REST API is 100. However, my new answer should print each repo in a newline, with 100 repositories.